How to create reverse proxy or forward request in Apache for soap service?
I've a soap service in address https://orash.ir/mis.asmx on windows server and also, I've https://wp.orash.ir on Ubuntu server.
I need to send request to https://wp.orash.ir/mis.asmx?..... and forward to https://orash.ir/mis.asmx then get response.
How can I do this with Apache?
I tried this configuration but does not work.
<VirtualHost wp.orash.ir.80>
ServerName wp.orash.ir

ProxyPreserveHost On

 <LocationMatch ^/custom>
    ProxyPass https://orash.ir/mis.asmx
    ProxyPassReverse https://wp.orash.ir/mis.asmx
</LocationMatch> 
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost wp.orash.ir.443>
ServerName wp.orash.ir

ProxyPreserveHost On

<LocationMatch ^/custom>
    ProxyPass https://orash.ir/mis.asmx
    ProxyPassReverse https://wp.orash.ir/mis.asmx
</LocationMatch>
        
SSLCertificateFile /**********/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /**********/privkey.pem   
Include /*************.conf     
</VirtualHost>

Thanx.
